# Qualtrics - Adding a footer below the Table of Contents button

Tags: javascript, css, qualtrics

I took this javascript off of the Qualtrics linkedin group (Thanks Anthony)

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
var para = document.createElement("footnote");
var test = document.getElementById("Buttons");
var node = document.createTextNode('This is your footnote');
var next = document.getElementById("NextButton");
para.appendChild(node);
test.insertBefore(para, next.nextSibling);

});
```

As he states in the discussion, using CSS styling in the footer should force the text to be below the buttons instead of next to it.

However, I'm terrible at CSS, so my question is a bit two fold:

1) I looked up how to do CSS styling on footers, but where would I put them in my survey? Also what would be the appropriate CSS? The Javascript goes into one question per page.

Taken from another stackoverflow question:

```
#footer-row1{
       margin-top: 80px;
       padding: 1.2em 0;

}
```

I've used CSS in my actual footer and header for the page in the Look and Feel, but I'm not sure how to only affect pages with my TOC button? The Table of Contents button is in the middle of the Back and Next buttons.

Where would I put it? On the last question on each page in the body of the question?

If anyone could help that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add a footer only on pages with a TOC button.  There are a couple of different ways to do it, but here is one way.  Under Look & Feel/Footer/Edit/Source:

```
<div id="TocFooter" style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 12px;">&nbsp;</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
if ($('JumpButton')) $('TocFooter').innerHTML = "This is my TOC footer text";
});
</script>
```

The `<div>` contains your footer text, currently centered with some padding below, but you can change it as needed.  It is just a space to begin with (`&nbsp;`).  The javascript checks to see if the page has a TOC button (id JumpButton), and if it does changes the space to some other text.

UPDATE:
Based on your comment below, to put something just below the buttons, add this javascript under Look&Feel/Advanced/Header/Edit/Source (it can go in either the Header or the Footer):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function () {
    if ($('JumpButton')) {
      $('Buttons').insert({
        after: "<div style=\"text-align:center;padding:12px 0px\">This is the TOC button footnote</div>"
      }); 
    }
});
</script>
```

This adds a centered `<div>` with 12px of padding top and bottom below the buttons.

Comment: Hi sorry, I don't really know (I just mentioned footer because that's what the person that wrote this code said), but I did try this and it ended up in the page footer? I already have a footer in there that I can't change. Is there a way to put it directly below the buttons instead of to the right of the next button?

Comment: Answer updated based on clarification in comment above.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked! (changed the alignment to right instead of center because that's where the buttons were). Are there materials or places where I can learn this? It seems super useful!

Comment: Other than general JavaScript and CSS, Qualtrics uses the Prototype JavaScript Framework, which very useful for things like this.  You can learn more about it here: [http://api.prototypejs.org](http://api.prototypejs.org).